# Use Recursion to print an array from [0,0,0,0] to [9,9,9,9]I

Tags: java, recursion

I just want to print an array from [0,0,0,0] to [9,9,9,9] using recursion. 
Firstly , I wrote the code as follows:

```
public class PrintNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 4;
        int[] number = new int[N];
        PrintNumber printNumber = new PrintNumber();
        printNumber.printNum(number,0);
    }
    public void printNum(int[] number, int bit) {
        if (bit == number.length ) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            number[bit] = i;
            /******** something goes wrong here ********/
            printNum(number, ++bit);
            /******** something goes wrong here ********/
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see , there not too much code , but it didn't work. 
So I debugged my code and I found out `++bit` (the last line of the code) should be written as `bit+1`. Then , it works well.

But I am really confused , why is that? `++bit` and `bit+1` are both to increase the bit by 1 , why it doesn't work for `++bit` and it works for `bit+1` ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: `bit+1` is an expression with the _result_ being the value of adding `1` to `bit`, with no _side effects_ (e.g. the value of `bit` will not be mutated), whereas `++bit` will yield as result the sum of `1` and `bit`, but as a side effect will increase the variable `bit` by one (specifically: increases `bit` by `1` and returns the new value as the result of the expression).

Comment: your code is iscorrect by the other reason. i will show asap

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `++bit` and `bit + 1`. The expression `++bit` desugars into what is essentially `bit = bit + 1`*. So your line becomes.

```
printNum(number, bit = bit + 1);
```

So the actual value of the variable `bit` is changing, and since you call this in a loop, the value is going to keep increasing, which is not desired. Eventually, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `bit` becomes too big for the array.

---

<sub>* It actually probably desugars into a more efficient JVM instruction, but semantically, it should be equivalent.</sub>

Comment: I haven't looked into what the JVM does.  But historically, this construct is from C which was first developed for PDP-11 processors.  The PDP-11 has instruction formats which will let you use a register as an array index **and** increment the index, either before or after using it, all in one instruction.  So in that case, using `bit++` or `++bit` is definitely more efficient.  As a separate statement (not as part of a larger expression), I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workable solution.

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class TestTest {
    private static int N = 4;
    private static int MAX = 10;
     public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] number = new int[N];
            TestTest printNumber = new TestTest();
            printNumber.printNum(number,0);
        }
        public void printNum(int[] number, int bit) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));
            if (bit == MAX ) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                number[i] = bit;
            }
            printNum(number, ++bit);
        }
}
```

There was several problems:

1. You mixed loop and recurection.
2. Wrong array sizes
3. Wrong array values
4. Wrong print if-case
5. Wrong function exit.

This code yeilds stackoverflow exception. but it works for `N = 3`:

```
public class TestTest {
    private static int N = 3;
    private static int MAX = 10;
     public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] number = new int[N];
            TestTest printNumber = new TestTest();
            printNumber.printNum(number);


        }
        public void printNum(int[] number) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));
//          if (bit == MAX) {
//              return;
//          }
            boolean exit = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                if (number[i] != MAX - 1) {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }
            if (exit) {
                return;
            }
            number[N - 1]++;
            for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (number[i] == MAX) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        number[i - 1]++;
                        number[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            printNum(number);
        }
}
```

Loop solution:

```
public class TestTest {
    private static int N = 4;
    private static int MAX = 10;
     public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] number = new int[N];
            TestTest printNumber = new TestTest();
//          printNumber.printNum(number);
            printNumber.printNumLoop(number);

        }
        private void printNumLoop(int[] number) {
            while(true) {

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));
                number[N - 1]++;
                for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                    if (number[i] == MAX) {
                        if (i > 0) {
                            number[i - 1]++;
                            number[i] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                boolean exit = true;    
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    if (number[i] != MAX - 1) {
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }
                if (exit) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
        public void printNum(int[] number) {

//          if (bit == MAX) {
//              return;
//          }
            boolean exit = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                if (number[i] != MAX - 1) {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }
            if (exit) {
                return;
            }
            number[N - 1]++;
            for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (number[i] == MAX) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        number[i - 1]++;
                        number[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            printNum(number);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I want , I want to print something like  [0000] ,[0001],[0002],[0003].....[9999]

Comment: @Leo_Wang , in question body it was not written.

Comment: @Leo_Wang , w8 for a bit

Comment: @Leo_Wang simple loop solution. recursion yeilds stackoverflow for 10000 depth;)